# UPDATE() Function (Insert and Update Triggers)

Tags: sql-server, database-design, t-sql, trigger

Is there a way to have the column name dynamic in this function? For example, passing a parameter to a variable named @FldName = 'Name'. e.g. UPDATE(@FldName). Basically, what I want to do is to have a uniform or standard code inside my trigger. If anyone have better solutions or better way to what I want to achieve, please help. Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of the trigger?  If you want to dynamically do things after an update or insert, why not just use a stored procedure?

Comment: Thanks for the response Queue Mann.  I tried to this but the inserted and deleted table will not work.  But if you have a code sample that do the same.  Will truly appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow.  What is preventing you from accessing a newly inserted row in a stored procedure?  Yes, in a trigger, you have access to the virtual tables, inserted and deleted, but that's a bit beside the point.

Comment: @Queue Mann - Thanks for response.  The requirement was to have the code inside the trigger standardize in which the developer will not define the columns in case there will be any modification in the table in the future.  Please let me know if I don't make any sense.  Thanks

Comment: You mean the trigger is on a table where the column names can change at anytime?  So you want the trigger to just automatically update another table with the new names without recoding it?  Sorry, I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Nice work thanks to Nigel Rivett for sharing his work... perfect

http://www.nigelrivett.net/AuditTrailTrigger.html

```
/*
This trigger audit trails all changes made to a table.
It will place in the table Audit all inserted, deleted, changed columns in the table on which it is placed.
It will put out an error message if there is no primary key on the table
You will need to change @TableName to match the table to be audit trailed
*/

--Set up the tables
if exists (select * from sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Audit]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [dbo].[Audit]
go
create table Audit (Type char(1), TableName varchar(128), PK varchar(1000), FieldName varchar(128), OldValue varchar(1000), NewValue varchar(1000), UpdateDate datetime, UserName varchar(128))
go
if exists (select * from sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[trigtest]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [dbo].[trigtest]
go
create table trigtest (i int not null, j int not null, s varchar(10), t varchar(10))
go
alter table trigtest add constraint pk primary key (i, j)
go

create trigger tr_trigtest on trigtest for insert, update, delete
as

declare @bit int ,
    @field int ,
    @maxfield int ,
    @char int ,
    @fieldname varchar(128) ,
    @TableName varchar(128) ,
    @PKCols varchar(1000) ,
    @sql varchar(2000), 
    @UpdateDate varchar(21) ,
    @UserName varchar(128) ,
    @Type char(1) ,
    @PKSelect varchar(1000)

    select @TableName = 'trigtest'

    -- date and user
    select     @UserName = system_user ,
        @UpdateDate = convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 112) + ' ' + convert(varchar(12), getdate(), 114)

    -- Action
    if exists (select * from inserted)
        if exists (select * from deleted)
            select @Type = 'U'
        else
            select @Type = 'I'
    else
        select @Type = 'D'

    -- get list of columns
    select * into #ins from inserted
    select * into #del from deleted

    -- Get primary key columns for full outer join
    select    @PKCols = coalesce(@PKCols + ' and', ' on') + ' i.' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ' = d.' + c.COLUMN_NAME
    from    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
    where     pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
    and    CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    and    c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
    and    c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

    -- Get primary key select for insert
    select @PKSelect = coalesce(@PKSelect+'+','') + '''<' + COLUMN_NAME + '=''+convert(varchar(100),coalesce(i.' + COLUMN_NAME +',d.' + COLUMN_NAME + '))+''>''' 
    from    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
    where     pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
    and    CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    and    c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
    and    c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

    if @PKCols is null
    begin
        raiserror('no PK on table %s', 16, -1, @TableName)
        return
    end

    select @field = 0, @maxfield = max(ORDINAL_POSITION) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = @TableName
    while @field < @maxfield
    begin
        select @field = min(ORDINAL_POSITION) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = @TableName and ORDINAL_POSITION > @field
        select @bit = (@field - 1 )% 8 + 1
        select @bit = power(2,@bit - 1)
        select @char = ((@field - 1) / 8) + 1
        if substring(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),@char, 1) & @bit > 0 or @Type in ('I','D')
        begin
            select @fieldname = COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = @TableName and ORDINAL_POSITION = @field
            select @sql =         'insert Audit (Type, TableName, PK, FieldName, OldValue, NewValue, UpdateDate, UserName)'
            select @sql = @sql +     ' select ''' + @Type + ''''
            select @sql = @sql +     ',''' + @TableName + ''''
            select @sql = @sql +     ',' + @PKSelect
            select @sql = @sql +     ',''' + @fieldname + ''''
            select @sql = @sql +     ',convert(varchar(1000),d.' + @fieldname + ')'
            select @sql = @sql +     ',convert(varchar(1000),i.' + @fieldname + ')'
            select @sql = @sql +     ',''' + @UpdateDate + ''''
            select @sql = @sql +     ',''' + @UserName + ''''
            select @sql = @sql +     ' from #ins i full outer join #del d'
            select @sql = @sql +     @PKCols
            select @sql = @sql +     ' where i.' + @fieldname + ' <> d.' + @fieldname 
            select @sql = @sql +     ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is null and  d.' + @fieldname + ' is not null)' 
            select @sql = @sql +     ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is not null and  d.' + @fieldname + ' is null)' 
            exec (@sql)
        end
    end
go
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @fldname varchar(max) = 'foo'

Declare @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) =
'
UPDATE TABLE
SET ' + @FldName + ' = bar
WHERE ' + @FldName + ' <> bar '

EXEC(@sql)
```

In this example, this sets @sql to:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET foo = bar
WHERE foo <> bar
```

And executes the script. Clearly, you would want to modify for your exact implementation.

**Expanded:**

Because you have to execute the dynamic sql and you cannot actually do that in a function, you have to wrap the dynamic sql in a procedure to do it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.update_field (@fldname VARCHAR(MAX)) 
AS 

Declare @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) =
'
UPDATE TABLE
SET ' + @FldName + ' = bar
WHERE ' + @FldName + ' <> bar '
EXEC(@sql)

CREATE FUNCTION UPDATE_FIELD (@fldname VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.update_field @fldname
RETURN 0
END
```

All of that said- I would heavily recommend a review of your architecture if you're forced to implement this as a solution.

Comment: Technically that works but I thought the question was 'foo' has to be a parameter.  Maybe the next time the trigger gets fired, he no longer wants 'foo' to be updated but rather 'bar' instead.  I don't see how that can be done in a trigger.

Comment: That depends on the logic behind what he wants to do- if it's possible to derive the name of the field he wants to update in the trigger, he can pass it into @fldname. Heck, we could wrap the whole thing in a stored procedure and call that in the trigger with the parameter value.

Comment: I don't think this is relevant? Pretty sure they are asking about this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx

Comment: You can create a function that calls your custom stored procedure but you will get this error when you try running it: `Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.`